# How do I get CocoaPods pod download stats?

Tags: download, statistics, cocoapods

I need to report download stats for a CocoaPod package. How do I do that?

For PyPI, I can get them from: https://pypistats.org/

For npm packages, the stats are shown publicly e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/onnxruntime-web

For maven, I can see the stats if I login: https://oss.sonatype.org/#central-stat

What is the equivalent for CocoaPods?

Answer (score 1):

I think such stats [existed](https://blog.cocoapods.org/Stats/) back in 2015 but was discontinued due to lack of financial support for the data storage.

The [code](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-stats) was written in ruby.
An option is to reverse engineer for your use case.